# check data before insert to database Laravel

Tags: database, laravel, duplicates

have some question, looking for some suggestion how to make a check before insert data to database. I want to add member to a team, but I need to check if its already exist or not. Otherwise without check its doing duplicats. User can belongs to same team +1000 times. 
I have a table with name: Teammembersall where I'm adding storing TeamId , UserId data (this is how I can identify to which team user belongs). 
But before I add a user to team, I need to check somehow maybe this user already belongs to a team. To do not duplicate it.
Maybe some suggestions how to do that?

This is my controller:

```
 public function insertUserToTeam(Request $req)
{
    $teamNameSelectBoxInTeamMembers = $req->input('teamNameSelectBoxInTeamMembers');
    $userNameSelectBoxInTeamMembers = $req->input('userNameSelectBoxInTeamMembers');

    $data = array(
        'TeamId' => $teamNameSelectBoxInTeamMembers,
        'UserId' => $userNameSelectBoxInTeamMembers
    );

    DB::table('teammembersall')->insert($data);

    session()->flash('msg', 'Successfully done!.');
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

And this is my view blade:

```
<div class="container" id="container-home-bottom">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-2">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card-header">Add User to Team</div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <p id="note-assist">Can find your team? <a href="{{ route('teamCreate') }}">Create new Team!</a></p>
                <form action="/insertUserToTeam" method="post">
                    {{csrf_field()}}

                    <div class="form-group" >
                        <label for="sel1">Select your team:</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="sel2" name="teamNameSelectBoxInTeamMembers" required>
                            <option selected disabled hidden>Select a team</option>
                                @foreach ($team as $teams_each)
                                    <option value="{!! $teams_each->teamId !!}">{!! $teams_each->name !!}</option>
                                @endforeach

                        </select>
                        <br>

                        <label for="sel2">Select user:</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="sel3" name="userNameSelectBoxInTeamMembers">
                            <option selected disabled hidden>Select user</option>
                            @foreach ($users as $user_each)
                                <option value="{!! $user_each->id !!}">{!! $user_each->name !!}</option>
                            @endforeach

                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <input id="add-team" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" name="submitEditTeamCompany" value="Add to Team">
                </form>
                <br>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check if the userid and teamid is already present in that table:

```
public function insertUserToTeam(Request $req)
{
    $teamNameSelectBoxInTeamMembers = $req->input('teamNameSelectBoxInTeamMembers');
    $userNameSelectBoxInTeamMembers = $req->input('userNameSelectBoxInTeamMembers');


    $data = array(
        'TeamId' => $teamNameSelectBoxInTeamMembers,
        'UserId' => $userNameSelectBoxInTeamMembers
    );

    $count = DB::table('teammembersall')->where('TeamId', $teamNameSelectBoxInTeamMembers)
                                ->where('UserId',  $userNameSelectBoxInTeamMembers)
                                ->count();

    if($count > 0){
        // This user already in a team
        //send error message
    }else{
        DB::table('teammembersall')->insert($data);
    }

    session()->flash('msg', 'Successfully done!.');
    return redirect()->back();
}
```